# Video choppy in chromecast

Tags: google-chrome, video, mp4, chromecast

We tried use the sample chromecast receiver to play this video:

https://d2ufudlfb4rsg4.cloudfront.net/kptv/g2jZazHPc/hd720/g2jZazHPc.mp4

somehow the video buffers a lot and it's very choppy. We definitely have very good internet connections. The video also seems to be choppy in chrome desktop browser but plays fine in Firefox.

Any suggestions or any settings we can tweak to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One reason the video may be choppy is that the file is simply being presented as a static asset on Amazon's Cloudfront service, which means you are not leveraging their streaming capabilities.

This is especially important as you have only a single copy of the video and it is quite a high bit rate - so there is no option for the browser to request a lower bit rate to avoid buffering etc.

Cloudfront will support adaptive bit rate streaming, which breaks the video into chunks and adjusts the bit rate delivered to match the network conditions, using streaming formats like HLS and MPEG DASH. This is the same technique Netflix etc use and you can see more info here:

- https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/

Its is more work up front for you but it will provide a better experience.

Having said that, static video will work albeit with possible buffering issues as your example shows, and the more interesting question is probably why it is behaving differently on chrome than other browsers.

Sadly, this is not an uncommon question in the video domain.

Having done some quick tests it does appear on a MAC to be choppy on Chrome and smoother on Safari, although Safari does generate an error:

> Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load

Unfortunately, the video world has so many combinations of encoding formats (h.264, vp9 etc), encoder profiles (baseline, main etc), containers (mp4, m4v, avi etc) and streaming formats (HLS, Smoothstreaming, DASH etc) that issues like this often are down to a particular video have some property that is not well supported on a given device or browser.

A simple test, to try to rule out any server or client issues and to narrow down the problem is to try with some known working videos, and with different bit rates.

One common source for  test video is here:

- https://peach.blender.org

One final thing to note is that there are recurring threads on difficulties playing videos using the M4V container, which your video uses, on chrome. As your video actually plays, this is probably not the issue and the choppiness is much more likely to be simply the large bit rate of the file, but if in testing your scenario you find that mp4 regularly plays better than m4v it may be something to look at.